# Is there any evidence that Rufus Carlin is named after the character (and actor) from Bill and Ted's Excellent Adventure?

Tags: inspiration, bill-and-ted, timeless

In the show [*Timeless*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeless_(TV_series)) - a show about time travel - Malcolm Barrett's character is named [Rufus Carlin](http://timeless.wikia.com/wiki/Rufus_Carlin). In the movie [Bill and Ted's Excellent Adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_%26_Ted%27s_Excellent_Adventure) - a movie about time travel - George *Carlin* plays a character named *Rufus*.

This seems like it's very obviously an homage, but I'm wondering if anyone behind the scenes has commented on the reasons behind the character's name.

Comment: Do you want to write a wiki for [tag:timeless], by the way? You asked the first question, so you probably know something about it.

Comment: @Adamant I've only seen the first three episodes, but I gave it a try.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Yes

There are more name Easter Eggs than just that one.  *Timeless* has a character named Lucy Preston. *Bill and Ted’s Excellent Adventure* has a character named *Bill* Preston. *Timeless* has a character named Wyatt Logan; *Bill and Ted’s Excellent Adventure* has a character named *Ted* Logan.

This has been confirmed in an [interview](http://www.popsugar.com/entertainment/Abigail-Spencer-Interview-About-Timeless-42553687) with Abigail Spencer, who plays Lucy Preston:

> PS: I couldn’t help but notice that the three main characters have
> similar names to the characters in the ‘80s movie Bill & Ted’s
> Excellent Adventure. Is that purposeful?
>
> AS: Yes! Good for you. You’re one of the only people that have caught
> that. With Eric and Shawn, everything is purposeful. There are Easter
> eggs all over the place. They are so good about weaving in other shows
> or other characters or other stories, and they’re doing that on
> purpose. We want to be part of the time-traveling family. We want to
> be in line with what was created before. So yes, there are some great
> nods.

Comment: you might want to mention that **Wyatt** Earp appears in the B&T animated series

Comment: @Valorum - That’s a good point.

Comment: I'm glad I asked this, I didn't even notice that the other two characters were named Logan and Preston! Thanks!